# The ratio / availability / added on / completed on / etc info in uTorrent?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

In bittorent we have these useful info like:

[image: http://screenshoot.me/67LdT]

But why don't we have these info in uTorrent?

[image]

Like say at a glance, I can see the "problematic downloads" in bittorrent:

[image]

But there's no way for us to see the ratio / availability of all the files in uTorrent?

Comment: I believe it's in another tab.

Comment: @digitxp I don't quite get you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all there, you have to enable the columns.  Right click on the "column bar" and enable them.  So right click on "Ratio" for instance and it will display a list of all the available columns.

Comment: Nice =D way to go